# Calling at the users at once and disconnect other calls if any one of the user receives the call

Tags: laravel, twilio, twilio-php

I want to have the round robin call functionality using twilio.

Let's say. I have 100 users and their phone numbers.

I want to call of them at the same time.

Then whoever the first person receives the call I will connect that call to my sales department and immediately cut or disconnect a the other calls.

I known through twiML I could dial to my sales team and I also know I could check the in-progess event to check to see call is connected.

However I am stuck at calling all my users at the same time and disconnecting after the first user is connected to the call which is my first step.

**i am making more updates as my scenario has been changed a little.**

in this case i am first calling the user who has filled out my lead form. once the lead user receives the call then i am going to call 10 agents from my sales team but i want to track which agent has received the lead call and want to save the agent information into my database and cut the other calls.

in my countroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Listing;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
use Twilio\TwiML\VoiceResponse;
use Twilio\Twiml;


class TwilioController extends Controller
{
    public function leadCall(Request $request)
    {
        // Lead user
        $lead = Lead::where('id', $request->lead_id)->first();
    
        $country_code = "+1";
        $visitor_phone = $country_code . $lead->details_phone;
        $url = "https://www.samplewebsite.com/outbound?multi_call=true";

        // Twilio Credentials
        $AccountSid = 'xyz';
        $AuthToken = 'xyz';
        
        $twilio_number = "123";

        $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

        
    
        // Calling the lead visitor first
        try {
            $call = $client->account->calls->create($visitor_phone, $twilio_number,
                array(
                    "url" =>  $url
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    if($request->multi_call)
    {
        // Fetch 10 agents
        $users = User::all()->take(10);

        // Calling Twilio
        $twiml = new VoiceResponse();
        $twiml->say('Please hold, we are connecting your call to one of our agent.', array('voice' => 'alice'));
        
        $dial = $twiml->dial();
        
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if($user->phone && $user->live_call)
            {
                $dial->number($user->phone,
                ['statusCallbackEvent' => 'answered',
                'statusCallback' => 'https://www.samplewebsite.com/outbound?agent_call=true',
                'statusCallbackMethod' => 'GET']);
            }
        }


        $response = response()->make($twiml, 200);
        $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        return $response;
    }

    if($request->agent_call)
    {
        return "Call was made to: " . $request->to;
    }


}
```

this is what i have done so far

and in routes file

```
Route::post('lead-call', 'TwilioController@leadCall')->name('leadCall');

Route::get('outbound', 'TwilioController@outboundMultiCall');
```

And TwiML resonse

```
<Response>
<Say voice="alice">Please hold, we are connecting your call to one of our agent.</Say>
<Dial>
<Number statusCallbackEvent="answered" statusCallback="https://www.samplewebsite.com/outbound?agent_call=true" statusCallbackMethod="GET">xxx-xxx-xxxx</Number>
<Number statusCallbackEvent="answered" statusCallback="https://www.samplewebsite.com/outbound?agent_call=true" statusCallbackMethod="GET">xxx-xxx-xxxx</Number>
<Number statusCallbackEvent="answered" statusCallback="https://www.samplewebsite.com/outbound?agent_call=true" statusCallbackMethod="GET">xxx-xxx-xxxx</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

i am having two problems. when i add the get parameter like multi_call=true in my webhook then i get application error. so i can't make 10 dials to my agents.

plus i want to keep track of which user has attend the call first so i could maintain into my database and increase their rating.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is working and what is not working?

Comment: @philnash up am able to call one user and connect to my sales team. I have updated my question. I am stuck at calling at the users at the same time and disconnect all the other calls if the any one of the user attends the call.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First, I just need to warn you that by default Twilio accounts have a [limit of creating 1 call per second](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180028-How-fast-can-I-place-or-receive-phone-calls-with-Twilio-), so with any code, you calls will still be placed sequentially.

If you can make one call then you can make more than one call at a time. You need to loop through the numbers you want to place calls to and make an API request for each call you want to create.

The next part is to cancel the other calls once one call connects. When you create the call, you will receive a response from the API with the call SID. Once your first call connects, you will receive a webhook to your application. The parameters will include the call SID. So, to cancel the other calls you need to take the list of call SIDs that you have created remove the one that connected and then make [API calls to update the the other calls to the "completed" status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-call-resource-to-end-the-call&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x), which will hang up the call.

**Edit:**

I see that you're connecting your outbound call first, then using TwiML to multi-dial. That should work, there's just a couple of things you've done wrong.

First, you are using multiple [`<Dial>`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) instead of multiple [`<Number>`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) within a `<Dial>` to make the multi calls. Try the following:

```php
    public function outboundMultiCall(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->multi_call)
        {
            // Fetch 10 agents
            $users = User::all()->take(10);

            // Calling Twilio
            $twiml = new VoiceResponse();
            $twiml->say('Please hold, we are connecting your call to one of our agent.', array('voice' => 'alice'));
            
            $dial = $twiml->dial();
            
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $dial->number($user->phone);
            }

            $response = response()->make($twiml, 200);
            $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            return $response;
        }

        return 'Some other action based on GET URL paramter';
    }
```

Second, Twilio webhooks are `POST` requests by default. So, you should either turn your route into a `POST`:

```php
Route::post('outbound', 'TwilioController@outboundMultiCall');
```

Or, you can pass a `method` parameter when you create the call:

```php
$call = $client->account->calls->create($visitor_phone, $twilio_number,
    array(
        "url" =>  $url,
        "method" => "GET"
    )
);
```

Finally, to record who answers the call you can use a [`statusCallback` URL attribute on the `<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback). Twilio will send a webhook when the call transitions into a new state. [The events](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback-event) are "initiated", "ringing", "answered" and "completed". The webhook will include all the normal [voice call parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters) so you can tell who the call was made to with the `To` parameter. There are [extra parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#status-callback-http-parameters) too, which might be useful.

Comment: my scenario has been changed a little. this time i am first calling my lead user then call 10 of my agents. one of them receives it then disconnect the other calls. but i want to keep track of which agent has receives the call.

Comment: And what problems are you having building that feature?

Comment: i have added my code to the post so its easier to see what i am doing wrong here. i belive i am very close but not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: let me know what you think about it. i have posted my code

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code @Jonib, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insights. i have updated my code but for some reason i think i am stuck with the second webhook part i have struggled with it for countless hours.

Comment: What are you stuck with now? What have you done, what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: I believe it is something has to do with the TwiML. i have pasted the TwiML response.
All i want if someone receives the call then i want to track their phone number. thats all.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the TwiML, that seems fine. What is actually not working though, it’s hard to help debug if all you say is that you’re stuck. What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?